# What does a leading `\x` mean in a Python string `\xaa`

Tags: python, string, escaping

What is difference between `'aa'` and `'\xaa'`? What does the `\x` part mean? And which chapter of the Python documentation covers this topic?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The leading `\x` escape sequence means the next two characters are interpreted as hex digits for the character code, so `\xaa` equals `chr(0xaa)`, i.e., `chr(16 * 10 + 10)` -- a small raised lowercase `'a'` character.

Escape sequences are documented in a short table [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in the Python docs.

Comment: chr(170) can be interpreted without reference to a particular encoding only in the context of Python 3.X, and it's actually a "feminine ordinal indicator" ... a peculiarity of Spanish orthography, along with its sibling U+00BA "masculine ordinal indicator".

Comment: what do you do if you want to have more than 2 hex digits

Comment: @Hippolippo `\u` is the same but for up to 4 hex digits, and `\U` is the same but for up to 8 hex digits. More than this will not be needed, because of how Unicode is designed.

Answer (score -10):

That's unicode character escaping. See "Unicode Constructors" on [PEP 100](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0100/)

Comment: No it isn't. It's for defining a specific byte in a `str`, not for making a unicode code point, which is done with the `u'\u...` notation.

Comment: @Mike, @Jake: It's for BOTH. '\xaa' is a str object. u'\xaa' is a unicode object. `print repr(unichr(170))` produces `u'\xaa'`

Comment: Oops. I seem not to have noticed the IronPython tag. *blush*. The concepts in my comment are still pretty pertinent—`\x` and `\u` remain somewhat different things.