# Python - hashing binary value

Tags: python, sha1

I wanted to use sha1 alghoritm to calculate the checksum of some data, the thing is that in python `hashlib` input is given as string.

Is it possible to calculate sha1 in python, but somehow give raw bytes as input?

I am asking because if I would want to calculate hash of an file, in C I would use `openssl` library and just pass normal bytes, but in Python I need to pass string, so if I would calculate hash of some specific file I would get different results in both languages.

Comment: Well, you could convert the text in the file to ascii and fire it through `hashlib`. I only think it makes difference for encodings other than single-byte.

Comment: I done some more reading and after viewing this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672326/what-does-leading-x-mean-in-a-python-string-xaa i think I can use struct module to build this byte-string representation of anything and pass it to hashlib. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Unless you know for certain that you are using a multi-byte charset in the file you want to hash, you can just pass it to the hashing function like you'd do in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `str` objects can be arbitrary byte streams. So yes, you can just pass the data into the `hashlib` functions as `str`s.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> "this is binary \0\1\2"
'this is binary \x00\x01\x02'
>>> hashlib.sha1("this is binary \0\1\2").hexdigest()
'17c27af39d476f662be60be7f25c8d3873041bb3'
```

Comment: Thanks, knowing this I can also use struct module to compute hash of for example for 4 byte integer.

Comment: @Andna you could do that with your old C hashing library too. I'm not sure why you'd involve the `struct` module for any of this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you asking what I want to do this in Python?

Comment: No you cannot. Try `hashlib.sha1(u'\xcc\x88u')` and see.

Comment: @SassaNF that's because the `u'...'` causes the string to be a `unicode` object instead of a `str` object. To turn a `unicode` object into a `str`, you'll need to encode it. e.g. `hashlib.sha1(u'\xcc\x88u'.encode("utf-8"))`

Comment: Right. `'\xcc\x88u'` was already meant to be a UTF-8 encoding of a Unicode sequence U+0308 and `u`. So I started from the wrong place, and need to work out why it ends up `u'...'`, not `'...'`.