# What is str() representing here?

Tags: python, security, networking

I am a beginner Python programmer and I really like security in general. However, I am learning, and today I stumbled upon a [Python script](https://github.com/vpnguy/ntpdos/blob/master/ntpdos.py) that easily allows to use NTP servers to perform a DoS attack using amplification provided by a NTP 'vulnerability'.

If you look at the script, line 18, you will see:

```
data=str("\x17\x00\x03\x2a") + str("\x00")*4
```

However, if I go to the Python console and try to print it, what it is returned has no sense:

```
>>> str("\x17\x00\x03\x2a") + str("\x00")*4
*
```

Obviously I am missing something here but I do not know how to find it out. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672326/what-does-leading-x-mean-in-a-python-string-xaa perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `str()` calls are *entirely redundant*.

The following produces the same value:

```
data = "\x17\x00\x03\x2a" + "\x00" * 4
```

That's 4 bytes, hex values 17, 00, 03 and 2a, followed by 4 00 bytes.

`\xhh` is a Python escape sequence used to define bytes by their hex codepoint; `\x61` would the lowercase `'a'`, as that's the hex code for that ASCII character:

```
>>> '\x61'
'a'
```

where the Python prompt echos the string back to me as `'a'` because it is printable. Non-printable characters are shown using their escape codes still.

The string doesn't contain (much) printable data, these are bytes mostly outside the ASCII printable range:

```
>>> data = "\x17\x00\x03\x2a" + "\x00" * 4
>>> data
'\x17\x00\x03*\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Only the `\x2a` byte is a printable ASCII character, the one lonely `*` you see.

So, when you *`print`* that value, Python tries to write the exact bytes to your console, but only one of those actually makes sense to your console, resulting in a visible character.