# What does the "\x5b\x4d\x6f etc.." mean in Python?

Tags: python, buffer, metasploit

this is my first post on here so please excuse me if I have made any mistakes.

So, I was browsing around on the Metasploit page, and I found these strange types of codes. I tried searching it on google and on here, but couldn't find any other questions and answers like I had. I also noticed that Elliot used the method in "Mr. Robot" while programming in Python. I can see  that the code is usually used in viruses, but I need to know why. This is the code that I found using this method:

> buf +=
>   "\x5b\x4d\x6f\x76\x69\x65\x50\x6c\x61\x79\x5d\x0d\x0a\x46\x69\x6c\x65\x4e\x61\x6d\x65\x30\x3d\x43\x3a\x5c"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a leading \`\x\` mean in a Python string \`\xaa\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672326/what-does-a-leading-x-mean-in-a-python-string-xaa)

Comment: Also might be something along the lines of  [obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a string, just as any other string like `"Hello World!"`. However, it's written in a different way. In computers, each character corresponds to a number, called a code-point, according to an encoding. One such encoding that you might have heard of is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), another is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). To give an example, in both encodings, the letter `H` corresponds to the number 72. In Python, one usually specifies a string using the matching letters, like `"Hello World!"`. However, it is also possible to use the code-points. In python, this can be denoted with `\xab`, where `ab` is replaced with the hexadecimal form of the code-point. So `H` would become `'\x48'`, because 48 is the hexadecimal notation for 72, the code-point for the letter `H`. In this notation, `"Hello World!"` becomes `"\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21"`.

The string you specify consists of the hexadecimal code-point `5b` (decimal  91, the code-point for the character `[`), followed by the code-point `4d` (`M`), etc., leading to the full string `[MoviePlay]\r\nFileName0=C:\\`. Here `\r` and `\n` are special characters together representing a line-break, so one could also read it as:

```
[MoviePlay]
FileName0=C:\\
```

In principle this notation is not *necessarily* found in viruses, but that kind of programming often requires very specific manipulation of numbers in memory without a lot of regard for the actual characters represented by those numbers, so that could explain why you'd see it arise there.

Answer (score 3):

The code is a sequence of ASCII character encoded in hex.
It can be printed directly.

```
print('\x5b\x4d\x6f\x76\x69\x65\x50\x6c\x61\x79\x5d\x0d\x0a\x46\x69\x6c\x65\x4e\x61\x6d\x65\x30\x3d\x43\x3a\x5c')
```

The result is:

```
[MoviePlay]
FileName0=C:\
```

Comment: I have no idea whether this piece of code is malicious. Film maker usually make use some kind of encoding to make their films mysterious (to the general public)

Comment: I just took this piece of code from google as an example, but I think it was this one: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/16153/

Comment: This kind of code obfuscation may protect it from the detection of anti-virus. However, i think anti-virus can detect the problem when it is decoded.

Answer (score -1):

They use Metasploit, msfvenom to be more specific, to create or generate shellcodes specially for crafted or exploited file such as documents (docs, ppt, xls, etc) with different encoding.