# Dart is not printing hex string

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, hex

I got the string `\x01\x01` from a tcp/ip socket, when I try to print it to console, no output is coming

```
void main() {
  
  var out = "\x01\x01";
  print("printing out as --> $out <--");
  final runes = out.runes.toList();
  print(runes);

}
```

It gives the output as

```
printing out as -->  <--
[1, 1]
```

dart pad link: https://dartpad.dev/?id=854e4479bfec03d7e8fd40621c845567

I tried to use [hex package](https://pub.dev/packages/hex) and it gives `Non-hex character detected` error.

Questions.

1. How do I print these types of strings to the console?
2. If some conversion is needed, how do I know data belongs to these type ?

my socket client is like the following

```
  socket.listen(
    // handle data from the server
    (Uint8List data) async {
      var serverResponse = String.fromCharCodes(data);
      print('Server: $serverResponse');
      final runes = serverResponse.runes.toList();
      print(runes);
    },
```

**EDIT**

The socket server is the x0vnc server, on reading the input with wire shark I can see the server sent `01 01`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To display a hexa, you have to escape the characters like this:

```
  var out = '\\x01\\x01';
```

this will work.

Comment: Actually, my socket server sends 
```
ab =  b'\x01\x01'
 conn.send(ab)
```
which I don't have access to edit, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2672338/6531633 that is a valid hex string only

Comment: If you just want to visualize the hexa code, replace the lower case x's with the upper case like this: print('printing out as --> ${out.replaceAll('\\x', 'X')} <--');

Comment: why do we have to replace \x with X?

Comment: It all depends on how you want to manipulate this result, I suggest that if you want to see the result, change the lowercase x to uppercase so that you no longer have a hexa. If you want to use it differently, you have to create your own logic of use, so you avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have misunderstood what the server is sending.

Given you've not stated the server language I'm going to guess that ` ab = b'\x01\x01'  generates a  array with two bytes both with the value 1.

If you treat this as an ASCII value then 1 is a non printable character.

As such you need to iterate over the array and convert each byte into a suitable visual format.

This might mean that when you see a 1 you print x01.

Edit:

actually dart will convert an int to a string for you:

```dart
void main() {
  final bytes = <int>[1, 2, 3];

  for (final byte in bytes) {
    print(byte.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: The server is x0vnc server, I'm trying to read its packets with dart.
The server is sending `0101`, and unable to successfully read and decode it, Then I used a python client to read it, hence I found the data `b'\x01\x01`

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example.